# Change emoji Icon default drawings

Tags: java, android, emoji

I read that it is not possible to add emojiIcons in Android, because they all have a given code and all apps use this same code to display Emojis. But given that a lot of apps have slightly different emoji icons design, it must be possible to redefine a custom set of emoji design that won't be used anywhere else. Do you have any idea how to do this ?

For example, U+1F42F is a tiger face. Now, let's say I want to have a snow tiger instead of the regular tiger. Would it be possible to draw a snow tiger, put it somewhere in my code and then everytime the user will select the tiger emoji, the snow tiger will be shown instead ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible. What you need is a separate font, and [that's easy on android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource). You can also add new emoji by adding new characters to the [unicode private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) of your font.

Designing/adapting fonts is off-topic for this site... and I don't know the first thing about it.